# Attempting to edit a Sqlite entry with Flask-SqlAlchemy but receive an error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

When trying to edit a row, on submit I get this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) Error binding parameter 1: type 'StringField' is not supported
[SQL: UPDATE blog_post SET title=?, subtitle=?, body=?, author=?, img_url=? WHERE blog_post.id = ?]
[parameters: (<wtforms.fields.simple.StringField object at 0x0000020F99680610>, <wtforms.fields.simple.StringField object at 0x0000020F99680C10>, <flask_ckeditor.fields.CKEditorField object at 0x0000020F99682250>, <wtforms.fields.simple.StringField object at 0x0000020F99682ED0>, <wtforms.fields.simple.StringField object at 0x0000020F99682310>, 2)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

I am not trying to insert another data type, everything is a string. Here is my table:

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
```

Below is my code to edit an entry:

```
@app.route("/edit/<int:post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_post(post_id):
    with app.app_context():
        post = db.session.query(BlogPost).filter_by(id = post_id).first()
        print(post.__dict__)
        # post_data = CreatePostForm(obj=post)
        post_data = CreatePostForm(
                title = post.title,
                subtitle = post.subtitle,
                author = post.author,
                img_url = post.img_url,
                body = post.body
            )
        if post_data.validate_on_submit():
            print(post.title)
            post.title = post_data.title
            post.subtitle = post_data.subtitle
            post.author = post_data.author
            post.img_url = post_data.img_url
            post.body = post_data.body
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('show_post', index = post_id))
        return render_template('make-post.html', form = post_data, is_edit = True)
```

I don't know where this ProgrammingError is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was updating the SqlAlchemy row with data from a Flask-WTF form. I forgot to use the [data](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.data) attribute. So post.title = post_data.title.**data**

My variable declarations were also confusing, post_data should be something like edit_blog_form
so post.title = edit_blog_form.title.data

```
@app.route("/edit/<int:post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_post(post_id):
    with app.app_context():
        post = db.session.query(BlogPost).filter_by(id = post_id).first()
        print(post.__dict__)
        # post_data = CreatePostForm(obj=post)
        edit_blog_form= CreatePostForm(
                title = post.title,
                subtitle = post.subtitle,
                author = post.author,
                img_url = post.img_url,
                body = post.body
            )
        if post_data.validate_on_submit():
            post.title = edit_blog_form.title.data
            post.subtitle = edit_blog_form.subtitle.data
            post.author = edit_blog_form.author.data
            post.img_url = edit_blog_form.img_url.data
            post.body = edit_blog_form.body.data
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('show_post', index = post_id))
        return render_template('make-post.html', form = post_data, is_edit = True)
```